# How to disambiguate between function calls via trait function impl and struct impl in Rust?

Tags: rust, traits

The example code below demonstrates implementation of a trait for two structs, as well as a "native?" impl for functions with the same name for the two structs directly. (Hope that makes sense.)

If that wasn't clear:

- There is a trait which defines a function with the name `get_field_helper_function`
- This trait is `impl`'d for two `struct`s
- The same function name is used as part of an `impl` block for the same two structs

What I want to know is how to disambiguate between these two function calls.

The output from the example code below is included below the code itself.

What this demonstrates is that:

- The function `get_field_helper_function` is called from the struct impl rather than the trait impl
- If I remove this function, then the trait impl is called instead

But if both functions exist, I don't know how to disambiguate between them. It seems that trait implementations are lower priority than direct implementations.

---

#### Example Code

```
struct FirstType {
    
    field_1: String
}

impl FirstType {
    
    pub fn get_field_helper_function(&self) -> String {
        println!("FirstType::get_field_helper_function()");
        self.field_1.clone()
    }
}

struct SecondType {
    
    field_2: String
}

impl SecondType {
    
    pub fn get_field_helper_function(&self) -> String {
        println!("SecondType::get_field_helper_function()");
        self.field_2.clone()
    }
}

trait DTODynamic {

    fn get_field(&self) -> String;
    
    fn get_field_helper_function(&self) -> String;
}

fn from_str(struct_name: &str) -> Option<Box<dyn DTODynamic>> {
        
    match struct_name {
            
        "FirstType" => {
            let first = FirstType {
                field_1: String::from("first")
            };
                
            return Some(Box::new(first));
        }
        
        "SecondType" => {
            let second = SecondType {
                field_2: String::from("second")
            };
            
            return Some(Box::new(second));
        }
        
        _ => {
            return None;
        }
    }
}

impl DTODynamic for FirstType {
    
    fn get_field(&self) -> String {
        println!("DTODynamic::FirstType::get_field()");
        self.get_field_helper_function()
    }
    
    fn get_field_helper_function(&self) -> String {
        println!("DTODynamic::FirstType::get_field_helper_function()");
        self.field_1.clone()
    }
}

impl DTODynamic for SecondType {
    
    fn get_field(&self) -> String {
        println!("DTODynamic::SecondType::get_field()");
        self.get_field_helper_function()
    }
    
    fn get_field_helper_function(&self) -> String {
        println!("DTODynamic::SecondType::get_field_helper_function()");
        self.field_2.clone()
    }
}

fn main() {
    
    println!("constructing dynamic objects from function return value");
    
    let dynamic_thing = from_str("FirstType").expect("value was None");
    println!("dynamic_thing.get_field()={}", dynamic_thing.get_field());
}
```

#### Code Output

```
constructing dynamic objects from function return value
DTODynamic::FirstType::get_field()
FirstType::get_field_helper_function()
dynamic_thing.get_field()=first
```

This is the code output when the function `FirstType::get_field_helper_function` is removed.

```
constructing dynamic objects from function return value
DTODynamic::FirstType::get_field()
DTODynamic::FirstType::get_field_helper_function()
dynamic_thing.get_field()=first
```

Comment: It's such a shame that you always seem to be putting so much efford into asking your question  (they're always quite well written), but unfortunately they often end up being explained very well in either the documentation or in a previous question Stack Overflow, I really suggest you put more of that hard work into looking for an answer before creating a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The two function calls can be disambiguated in the usual way using the fully qualified syntax, but the key to the solution is that since in this particular instance the functions take a `&self` parameter, the form of the function call has to be modified since the usual form of

```
self.get_field_helper_function()
```

will not work. Instead, `self` must be passed explicitly as the first argument.

The following shows an example:

```
impl DTODynamic for FirstType {
    
    fn get_field(&self) -> String {
        println!("DTODynamic::FirstType::get_field()");
        DTODynamic::get_field_helper_function(self)
    }
    
    fn get_field_helper_function(&self) -> String {
        println!("DTODynamic::FirstType::get_field_helper_function()");
        //self.field_1.clone()
        self.get_field_helper_function()
    }
}
```